# iCal and Google Calendar creating double notifications

Tags: ical, google-calendar

I have a Google Calendar set up. I have set it up to send me E-Mail when an appointment is imminent.

I connected the calendar with my new MacBook Pro's iCal.

Now, **both** Google Calendar and iCal want to send me E-Mail notification. Google through their online service (which is what I want) and iCal through Mail.App (which I don't want).

I can't find any settings in iCal to turn E-Mail notification off. How do I prevent iCal from creating E-Mail reminders?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid getting double email notifications for appointments, you can turn off the alerts for the Google Calendar on the Mac as described in the [Calendar User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/set-event-alerts-and-receive-notifications-icl1012/11.0/mac/10.15):

> **Turn off alerts for a calendar**
>
> 1. In the Calendar app [image: Calendar app icon] on your Mac, Control-click the name of the calendar [*your Google Account name*] in the calendar list, then choose Get Info.
>
>    If you don’t see the calendar list on the left, choose View > Show Calendar List.
> 2. Select “Ignore alerts,” then click OK.

Note that this will turn off *all* alerts for Google Calendar that would be created on the Mac, that is, not only email notifications, but also notifications in the Notification Center.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an event by event basis. If you click on a particular event and select edit, in the Alert drop down menu there are several options - one of which is email. I'm guessing, that in your situation, all or most of your events are set to email you.

To fix that, you could either change all your events, or, if you would like to turn all notifications off, open iCal settings, click on the Advanced tab, select Turn Off all Events. This should disable even email alerts.

Comment: Cheers.  The thing is that I *do* want one of them to continue E-Mailing me - Google Calendar itself. So if I edit notification out of the event, Google will stop notifying me as well. Turning off *all* events is more than I want, but I will use it as a last resort if this can not be solved otherwise.

Comment: Do you know if changing it in iCal changes it in Google?

Comment: I assume so, as iCal seems to be using the settings I made in Google, and they are set up to synchronize with each other. But I will try out!

Comment: What did you find out?